# how to access TopicArn in Object/Array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am currently trying to implement Amazon SNS in a PHP learning project I am doing. I'm jkust wondering how can I print TopicArn from this object in PHP so I can use it in a variable whenever i need to use it in future code.

I was thinking it would be along the lines of `object(Aws\Result)#100->...` but i'm not sure

I tried `$TopicArn = $sns->get('TopicArn');` but this returned

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Aws\AwsClient::getCommand() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClientTrait.php on line 77 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClientTrait.php(77): Aws\AwsClient->getCommand('get', 'TopicArn') #1 /var/www/html/index.php(22): Aws\AwsClient->__call('get', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php on line 228
```

The end result should be `arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:321273dfffa23055886:testing22` stored in a variable

```
object(Aws\Result)#100 (2) {
  ["data":"Aws\Result":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["TopicArn"]=>
    string(44) "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:321273dfffa23055886:testing22"
    ["@metadata"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["statusCode"]=>
      int(200)
      ["effectiveUri"]=>
      string(35) "https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
      ["headers"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["x-amzn-requestid"]=>
        string(36) "b697234344422cvqe41a72-7f70-5ae6-a454dc-4e810f36483d"
        ["content-type"]=>
        string(8) "text/xml"
        ["content-length"]=>
        string(3) "316"
        ["date"]=>
        string(29) "Fri, 01 Mar 2019 17:38:14 GMT"
        ["connection"]=>
        string(5) "close"
      }
      ["transferStats"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["http"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["monitoringEvents":"Aws\Result":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Check `Aws\Result` class. There should be some getter method for that. You can edit your post and show us the  `Aws\Result` class if you like.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Result.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `$obj` is your object variable in PHP. Then you can do,

```
echo $obj->get('TopicArn');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Result.html) you can do it by using get method:

```
$yourObject->get("TopicArn");
```